# indexOf ignores second character in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm just studying JS and I need to write a program that checkes  if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.

I've made a code like this:

```
    function mutation(arr) {mutation: {
    var lowerCaseStringOne = arr[0].toLowerCase();
    var lowerCaseStringTwo = arr[1].toLowerCase();

    if (lowerCaseStringOne === lowerCaseStringTwo) {
        console.log(true);
        break mutation;
    }

    var newArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < lowerCaseStringTwo.length; i++){
        console.log(lowerCaseStringTwo[i]);
        if (lowerCaseStringTwo.indexOf(lowerCaseStringOne[i]) > 0) {
            newArray.push(lowerCaseStringTwo[i]);
            console.log('---');
        } 
    }

    var result = newArray.join("");

    if (result === lowerCaseStringTwo) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
}
}

mutation(["Mary", "Aarmy"]);
```

I think it's very complicated, but I can't solve the problem - the "indexOf" function seems to ignore a second character in my loop - loggs it in the console but doesn't pushes into an array. I thought it could happen because first and second letters are similar, but it's not. No matter what letter, it just ignores it.

Comment: I've just seen this mistake:
`if (lowerCaseStringTwo.indexOf(lowerCaseStringOne[i]) > 0)` this should be
`if (lowerCaseStringOne.indexOf(lowerCaseStringTwo[i]) > 0)`

Comment: Now it ignores the 'm' letter. I tryed so many ways of solving it, so I could have more mistakes...

Comment: sorry my fault haven't seen the other mistake before. You need to `>-1` as 0 is the index of the first letter

Comment: That's it! Just made the same edit and it worked! 

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexOf() will return 0 for the letter "a" in your example as the first instance is at position 0 in the array.

You should be using ">= 0"